# Specify Command for MenuItem in a DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, command

I have a context menu. It's bound to some collection and it has a defined ItemTemplate like this:

```
<ContextMenu
    ItemsSource={Binding ...}
    ItemTemplate={StaticResource itemTemplate}
    />
```

itemTemplate is a simple DataTemplate with a TextBlock:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="itemTemplate">
    <TextBlock Text={Binding ...} />
</DataTemplate>
```

How do I bind Command property for MenuItem to the underlying object's property?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think you need to wrap your TextBlock in a MenuItem:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="itemTemplate">
    <MenuItem Command={Binding ...}>
        <TextBlock Text={Binding ...} />
    </MenuItem>
</DataTemplate>
```

But I don't have an IDE in front of me right now to try this. Let me know how it goes.

---

Looks like you need to use the ItemContainerStyle as seen [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/okloeten/archive/2007/11/14/5149692.aspx). Sorry for leading you down the wrong path at the start there - but I got in front of an IDE and this works:

```
<ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding ...}"/>
    </Style>
</ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: Actually, this will add TextBlock to the MenuItem's Items collection. And it also puts MenuItem inside of another MenuItem.

Comment: But with your post I started thinking of templating MenuItem itself, this could be what i need.

Comment: This creates double MenuItem's, which f*cks up styling! Don't think this is an appropriate answer!

Comment: @Kolky - Read the second part of the answer where I correct myself. I didn't remove the incorrect first half because it had already been commented on.

Comment: Excuse me for my first reaction; that second solution is indeed working.

Comment: What if there is more than one menuitem and we need to bind the menu items with individual commands.

Answer (score 8):

Although this is only a slight variation on Martin Harris's answer, I thought I'd share it anyway.  I found it more useful specify a single command for the whole collection and also send along a CommandParameter:

```
<MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
       <Setter Property="Command" Value="{x:Static v:ViewModel.CommandForAll}"/>
       <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding ValueForCommand}"/>
    </Style>
</MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Then you can determine what to do in the handler for the command:

```
private void CommandForAll_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var cmdParam = e.Paramater as ExpectedType
    if (cmdParam != null)
        //DoStuff...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize I'm answering this quite a bit after the fact, but I ran into the same problem and the previous answers seemed to make binding to multiple different commands difficult.  The solution I arrived is very similar to MatrixManAtYrService's and works in 3 parts:

1) Bind the command using the ItemContainerStyle property to a command in the ViewModel -- this is the same as the previous answers. One exception is that I bind the CommandParameter to the MenuItem.

```
<Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
```

2) Create a custom class to define the look and behavior of each MenuItem. The ItemsSource of the menu will be set to a list of these. This is the same as other answers. However, in my implementation I have given the class an Action to be executed when the MenuItemCommand is invoked. I also included a boolean that will allow the MenuItem to be disabled.

```
public class MenuAction
{
    public string Name { get => name; set => name = value; }
    public Action Action { get => action; set => action = value; }
    public bool CanExecute { get => canExecute; set => canExecute = value; }
}
```

3) In the command implementation route control to the delegates in MenuAction.

```
public void HandleCommand(object sender)
{
    MenuItem clickedMenuItem = sender as MenuItem;
    MenuAction menuAction = clickedMenuItem?.DataContext as MenuAction;
    if(menuAction != null)
        menuAction.Action();
}

public bool CanMenuItemExecute(object sender)
{
    MenuItem clickedMenuItem = sender as MenuItem;
    MenuAction menuAction = clickedMenuItem?.DataContext as MenuAction;
    if (menuAction != null)
        return menuAction.CanExecute;
    else
        return false;
}
```

This should allow you to define all of the behavior of your commands in a list. While it is technically binding to a single command it is functionally similar to having multiple different commands. The same method should also work with nested MenuItems and HierarchicalDataTemplates with some tweaking.