# WPF ContextMenu with ItemsSource - how to bind to Command in each item?

Tags: wpf, binding, command, contextmenu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Specify Command for MenuItem in a DataTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898852/specify-command-for-menuitem-in-a-datatemplate)

I have a collection of objects (viewmodels) that represent menu items. Each of them have a command that I would like to execute when a MenuItem is clicked.

If I wanted to do the menu statically, I do it like this:

```
<ContextMenu>
    <MenuItem Header="{Binding Text1}" Command={Binding Command1}>
    <MenuItem Header="{Binding Text2}" Command={Binding Command2}>
</ContextMenu>
```

but when I don't know the items in advance (they come from a collection), I need to assign ContextMenu.ItemsSource - and put a text into a ItemTemplate.

```
<ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding MyMenuItems}">
    <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text2}" /> <!-- But where to put Command binding? TextBlock.Command makes no sense, and we have no access to MenuItem! -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
</ContextMenu>
```

This way, however, I have no place to bind a Command to - because I can't get the MenuItem for every row!

Any advice, please? Thank you, guys!

Comment: A duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/898852/specify-command-for-menuitem-in-a-datatemplate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/898852/specify-command-for-menuitem-in-a-datatemplate).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
<ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
  <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding AssociatedCommand}" />
  </Style>
</ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
```

where AssociatedCommand is the property on the viewmodel object that holds the ICommand.

Comment: Thanks, I already found a same answer in linked thread...

Comment: How do I separate commands for the two menu items.

Comment: How do I separate commands for multiple menu items? Let's say "Add" and "Remove".