# How to pass an index of a selected context menu item to a bound command?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, contextmenu

How could i bind all context menu items to one single command, which gets the index of the menu item called? I have a WPF/MVVM project.

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="cm" ItemsSource="{Binding ActionItems}" 
DisplayMemberPath="ActionDescription">    
</ContextMenu>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your should pass it as a `CommandParameter`:

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="cm" ItemsSource="{Binding ActionItems}" DisplayMemberPath="ActionDescription"
Command="{Binding YourCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding YourParameter}">
...
</ContextMenu>
```

*Updated*
you need the solution described here: [MVVM binding command to contextmenu item](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9994241/502950)

*Updated after comments*

relapse - than you should implement it as shown here: [WPF ContextMenu with ItemsSource - how to bind to Command in each item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580753/wpf-contextmenu-with-itemssource-how-to-bind-to-command-in-each-item). Please notice that link is a duplication of other question. So read the both please.

Comment: I don't have those tags within the ContextMenu block!

Comment: Which "those tags" you mean?

Comment: Sorry, my fault, I've given too little information. I can't set those properties for each context menu item explicitly because the items are taken from an ObservableCollection - the list of them is dynamic.

Comment: I've tried this variant but it doesn't execute the command:
`code`
<ContextMenu x:Key="cm" ItemsSource="{Binding ActionItems}" DisplayMemberPath="ActionDescription" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance ViewModel:MyViewModel}">
    <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding MyAction}" />
        </Style>
    </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
</ContextMenu>