# How do you bind a command to a MenuItem (WPF)?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, command, menuitem, relaycommand

Here is my code from the View.xaml.cs:

```
private RelayCommand _closeCommand;
public ICommand CloseCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_closeCommand == null)
        {
            _closeCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.OnClose());
        }
        return _closeCommand;
    }
}

public void OnClose()
{
    Close();
}
```

And here is some code from my View.xaml:

```
<Window.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem Name="menuItem_Close" Header="Close" Command="{Binding CloseCommand}" />
    </ContextMenu> 
</Window.ContextMenu>
```

When I run the program and select the close menu item, nothing happens. The CloseCommand code doesn't even get executed.

Comment: Did you set the DataContext?

Comment: I found the solution to my problem. I was using a ViewModel that had a property in it that was another ViewModel type and I needed to scope down to that propery by doing this: `Command="{Binding ActiveVM.CloseCommand}"`

Comment: I have found a solution to your question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/898852/specify-command-for-menuitem-in-a-datatemplate/18362041#18362041][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/898852/specify-command-for-menuitem-in-a-datatemplate/18362041#18362041

Answer (score 11):

`ContextMenu` is not part of the VisualTree, that's why the `DataContext` will not be inherited. Here [`ContextMenu.PlacementTarget`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.placementtarget.aspx) is some kind of relay to get the `Window`:

```
<MenuItem Name="menuItem_Close" Header="Close"
          Command="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext.CloseCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}" />
```

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't get the `DataContext`?  In my test it seems to be inheriting the DataContext as you would expect ...

Comment: I tried your code for the Command="..." but it did not work - just as before - nothing happed.

Comment: @dbaseman According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749018.aspx#PopupandtheVisualTree) Popup creates its own visualtree. This means no DataContext inheritance for ContextMenu which is placed in a Popup.

Comment: @JacksonDeanGoodwin Any binding errors? Are you sure that DataContext is set for Window? Maybe try a Button with your Command binding in Window directly for that.

Comment: Thanks for this. How should I bind a `static ICommand` to a MenuItem not using a ViewModel binding? I am currently using (which is not working) `Command="{x:Static ...}"` but that doesn't seem to work with the solution you have provided here. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, new answer. For me the problem was that `GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command.RelayCommand` didn't support closures for the action. RelayCommand stores a weak reference to the action so a closure gets deallocated almost immediately. The action must be a model method or be retained in some other way.

Answer (score -1):

for binding cross visual tree, refer to

[Binding Visibility for DataGridColumn in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22073740/binding-visibility-for-datagridcolumn-in-wpf)

or jsut try search BindingProxy