# How to implement commands on MenuItems

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, command, menuitem

In trying to bind a `Command` to a `MenuItem` in my program, I've found that `Commands` don't work with `MenuItems` like they do with other controls. I've been using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13826504/how-do-you-bind-a-command-to-a-menuitem-wpf) post as a guide, but have had no luck so far. Basically my goal is to run a `Command` when the `MenuItem` is clicked.

This is my xaml after looking at the previously mentioned post. My `Command` is called `CreateFiles`:

```
<MenuItem Header="{DynamicResource save}" Command="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext.CreateFiles, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}" />
```

My `Command` is created in the window's ViewModel and is declared like normal, but I will post it anyway:

```
private ICommand _createFiles;

public MainWindowViewModel()
{
   _createFiles = new Command(createFiles_Operations);
}

public ICommand CreateFiles { get { return _createFiles; } }
private void createFiles_Operations()
{

}
```

To test whether or not my `Command` is working I set a break point right at the first bracer. So far the program has not stopped at this break point when the `MenuItem` is clicked.

Since this method does not seem to work, what can I do to make `Commands` work with `MenuItems`?

**Update:** `Command` changed to `ICommand`

**Update 2:** `ContextMenu` & `Button` xaml:

```
<Button Click="Button_Click_1" Margin="5,4,0,0" Name="Button_1" Height="55" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="55" BorderBrush="Black">...

<ContextMenu x:Name="MainContextMenu" MouseLeave="ContextMenuMouseLeave" Background="White" BorderBrush="#FF959595" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">...
```

Comment: Where is the menuItem declared?

Comment: It's right there in the XAML. It's part of a `<Button.ContextMenu>` --> `<ContextMenu>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `Mode of RelativeSource` to `FindAncestor` to get `ContextMenu`:

```
<MenuItem Header="{DynamicResource save}"
          Command="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext.CreateFiles,
             RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                            AncestorType=ContextMenu}}" />
```

---

You have set `PlacementRectangle` property to refer to itself i.e.`ContextMenu`. Don't set that property, **`ContextMenuService` internally set `PlacementRectangle` to the element on which it is applied (in your case it will be Button).**

Remove this `PlacementRectangle="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"` from ContextMenu.

It should be:

```
<ContextMenu x:Name="MainContextMenu"
             MouseLeave="ContextMenuMouseLeave" Background="White"
             BorderBrush="#FF959595" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
```

Comment: I've changed my code to this. Is there any chance that there is something else that I need? My program does not stop at the break point in `createFiles_Operations()`.

Comment: Return type of `CreateFiles` should be `ICommand`. What's `Command`? Are you able to see any binding error in output window?

Comment: Is Button's DataContext point to `MainWindowViewModel` correctly?

Comment: There are no binding errors in the output window. I have updated my question to show `ICommand` instead of `Command`. As far as DataContext goes, this is set in the constructor of the window like so: `DataContext = App.MainWindowViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();`. I do not have the DataContext of the Button set separately.

Comment: Only reason i could think of is Button not inheriting DataContext from window or UserControl. Otherwise code looks exactly perfect.

Comment: Aren't you setting `DataContext` on ContextMenu?

Comment: Would you like to see the xaml of my button? Why would it not be inheriting the DataContect from the window? And No I am not.

Comment: I've posted the xaml for the `ContextMenu` and the `Button` that the `MenuItem` resides in.

Comment: I have updated an answer. Please check. Issue is in your ContextMenu declaration.